# how to load 2 hover effects at the same time

Tags: html, image, css, filter, hover

I have many images that all of them will have the same effect in hover, so I made to layers. I is the image and one is the hover effect.
http://jsfiddle.net/jmXdh/13/

So in hover the second layer loads, also i want to give an effect to the main image. only in hover.  As you can see I gave grayscale effect to it. but in hover, both 2 hovers don't load at the same time. why is that ?

this is what I got for the main image hover:

```
a:hover .img{-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}
```

Also I would it happen with transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a positive z-index value to your .play class to ensure that that element doesn't get pushed behind the image when the filter is applied to it.

Comment: Btw, do you know how can I add transition effect like this `-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;` to the blur effect ? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmXdh/22/)

Answer (score 1):

Any webkit css is only working to browsers that support webkit

The double hover effect is working.

I test it by changing the css a bit:

```
a:hover img{border:2px solid #F00;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmXdh/21/